# How do I test a model method that changes a separate model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm just starting to learn rspec and am having some trouble figuring out how to test a particular model method. Basically, I have a Thread model that users can reply to. Whenever a reply to that thread is saved, this method is run to update the `updated_at` column of the Thread.

```
def update_thread_timestamp
  Thread.where(id: thread_id).update_all("updated_at" => Time.now)
end
```

Here's my rspec test for that method:

```
it "#update_thread_timestamp updates the parent thread's updated_at column" do
  t = Factory.build(:thread, updated_at: nil)
  new_comment = Factory.build(:comment, thread_id: t.id)
  expect{new_comment.update_thread_timestamp}.to change{t.updated_at}
end
```

The problem here is that whenever I run the test it fails, with this:
`result should have changed, but is still nil`. Does rspec have an issue with direct DB calls? I'm at a loss on this one.

Comment: `update_all` executes a database query. (1) your `t` is never in the database, so it won't be affected. Use `FactoryGirl.create` instead of build. (2) the thread instance stored in `t` keeps its state in-memory. It won't be affected by the changes in the database. Try using `...to change(t.reload.updated_at)` instead.

Comment: @Raffael That worked perfectly! I had a feeling it was because t wasn't, in fact, in the database, but am still new enough at rspec that I hand no idea whether it mattered or not. Thanks!